# Object destructuring: Assign null values in one line

Tags: javascript, object

Assuming I have an object like this

```
foo = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
```

I would destructure it this way

```
const {a, b, c} = foo;
```

However, what, if the keys `a`, `b` and `c` do not exist?

```
foo = null;
```

This won't work then

```
const {a, b, c} = foo;
```

I would have to do something like

```
let a, b, c;

if(foo) {
    a = foo.a;
    b = foo.b;
    c = foo.c;
};
```

Is there a way to do this in one line? Something like

```
 const {a, b, c} = foo ? foo : null; // this is not working
```

> null is not an object. (evaluating '_ref2.a')

Comment: "*This won't work then*" what do you mean? It should work fine - you would get `a`, `b`, and `c` variables which are each `undefined`. Functionally identical to your "*I would have to do something like*" except that one leaves you with mutable variables, while the first one declares them as `const`.

Comment: @VLAZ nope. This gives me: `null is not an object. (evaluating '_ref2.a')`

Comment: [It shouldn't](https://jsbin.com/yojiyiyoci/edit?js,console). Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry I mistyped my Q. `foo = null` not `foo = {}`. Thats causing the confusion. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When foo is not an object, you are going to have to give it an object so the destructuring can happen. So set it to an empty object using an 'or'. Now if `foo` is defined it will use `foo`, if it is not defined it will use the default object.

```js
const foo = undefined;
const { a, b, c } = foo || {};
console.log(a, b, c);
```

If you want default values, set them in the object.

```js
const foo = undefined;
const { a, b, c } = foo || {a : 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };
console.log(a, b, c);
```

If you want default values if the object does not provide them all, you can set values in the destructuring.

```js
const foo = { a: 1};
const { a = "a", b = "b", c = "c" } = foo || {};
console.log(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about destructuring default parameters?
If foo could be undefined set  `= foo || {}` in destructuring to avoid exception

```js
let foo = {};
const {a = null, b = null, c = null} = foo;

console.log('a:', a);
console.log('b:', b);
console.log('c:', c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work like you might expect, the variables `a` `b` and `c` will be created with the value of `undefined`. this is the fallback when also trying to access a property which doesn't exist on a certain object.

```js
const foo = {};
console.log(foo.a); // undefined

const {a, b, c} = foo;

console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // undefined

console.log(d); // Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined
```